# Setup Database on Appharbor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I started an application with C# and MVC using code first to create my model.

My question is how to do you setup a sql database to run with [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).  I want to use the ASP.NET SQL profile provider for my users and also a database for the model that I created.

I have heard of SQL Migrations but not too familiar. Should I just use that to create a script and then manually build on AppHarbor using management studio and then just add the connection string as they suggest in AppHarbor to wire everything together?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am close to getting a live app but I cannot figure out how to setup the databases properly.

[Good blog post example that I found after asking this question](http://www.nashcoding.com/2011/02/05/using-the-forms-authentication-membership-provider-on-appharbor/comment-page-1/#comment-477)

Answer (score 2):

Creating your own:

```
var uriString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSERVER_URI"];
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = uri.Host,
    InitialCatalog = uri.AbsolutePath.Trim('/'),
    UserID = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').First(),
    Password = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').Last(),
}.ConnectionString;
```

developing the name:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstringname" connectionString="Server=localhost;
        Database=my-app-debug;User ID=test;Password=dfy5fgFdsvV;" />
<connectionStrings>
```

More info: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer

THIS IS A FAQ: theres info there where it shows when people run into a connection problem with management studio, it will be helpful.

http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: For whatever reason none of this is really registering. Can I just add the connection strings in web.release.config and leave everything else the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework, you should probably using [Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) functionality as well. With migrations your app update schema (if required) in each application start, so you need to only worry about right connection string that would point to AppHabor SQL instance.